# How to solve this quadratic equation in matrix $X$?

Tags: matrices, quadratics, matrix-equations

Given $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$  two  $m \times n$  real matrices, is there a closed form for the matrix equation
\begin{equation} 
\|\mathbf{X}\|^{2}_{F} - 2 \cdot \mbox{trace} (\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{A}) +\|\mathbf{B}\|^{2}_{F} = 0,
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $\| \cdot \|_{F}$ is the Frobenius norm? Notice that this equation can be viewed as a generalization of a simple quadratic equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$||X||_F^2=Tr(X^TX)$. So you can rewrite your equation in the following form:
$$
Tr(X^TX-2X^TA+B^TB)=Tr(X^TX-X^TA-A^TX+A^TA+B^TB-A^TA)=Tr((X-A)^T(X-A)+B^TB-A^TA)=0
$$
So 
$$
Tr(X-A)^T(X-A))=Tr(A^TA-B^TB);
$$
At least we  can understand now that  solution may exists only if $a=Tr(A^TA-B^TB)\ge 0$.
Now all matrices such that $||Y||_F^2=a$ will generate solution as $X=Y+A$.